# how to render component from onclick function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am working on react application.i need to render a gallery of photo when user click..i want to render from onclick function.But i am not able to handle.. my code is:

```
   <div onClick={this.handleClick} 
    style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightgoldenrodyellow', float: 'right' }}>
   </div>
```

my handle click function is this:

```
handleClick() {
    let images = [];
    {

      _.filter(this.props.data.gallery).map((photo) => {
        if (photo === null) {
          images.push(
            {
              src: emptyImage,
              thumbnail: emptyImage
            }
          )
        } else {
          images.push(
            {
              src: photo,
              thumbnail: photo
            }
          )
        }

      });
      console.log('1');
    console.log(images)
    console.log('2');
    return <Gallery images={images} enableImageSelection='true'  isOpen= {true} rowHeight='120' />;
    }

}
```

i am using react grid gallery for that.but onclick its not working.WHere I am doing wrong??

Comment: Yes agree with above. This is a dupe, and the answer there should help you.

Comment: let us know if you have any doubt or that ans fails to solve your issue.

Comment: yup its not working... i tried by going through refrence but not find solution